# In ClojureQL how can I make a where clause case insensitive?

Tags: clojure, clojureql

In ClojureQL how can I make a where clause case insensitive? I am trying to add UPPER or something to do this in the where clause but I can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ClojureQL you can call a function like this:

```
:function/col
```

So something like this should work according to the [documentation](http://www.clojureql.org/documentation.html):

```
(select (table :users) (where (= :LOWER/name john)))
```

Comment: I was getting "function lcase(character varying) does not exist". I changes it to LOWER though and it works now. Thanks!